# How can I detect that YouTube has finished video playback from injected script (using chrome extension)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I'm trying to make Chrome extension that invokes my function when video on watch page (like 'www.youtube.com/watch?=xxxxxxxx') finishes playback. I want to do that using an injected script.
Currently I'm using setInterval to check if `video.ended==true` but I would like to find a way to work without intervals and just use some event listener ideally.

I tried to add `onended` event listener to #movie_player and video elements, but that does not work. I also tried to listen to [`readystatechange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/readystatechange) but this one does not fire either. Adding `onplay` and `onplaying` event listeners to #movie_player doesn't fire as well.

Is there any way to do what I want to without using intervals?

Comment: Have you looked at the iframe API?

Comment: no, but YT watch pages dont have players inside of iframes. How can it help me then?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: document.querySelector('#player-container video').addEventListener('ended', console.log)

Comment: @wOxxOm it works. amazing. thank you. you could post it as proper answer to get some brownie points..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Events/ended) DOM event on the video element:

```
var videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
videoElement.addEventListener('ended', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});
```

Note, Youtube site uses AJAX navigation, which means your extension's content script runs only one time when the site is opened in any given tab. Add a listener for `yt-navigate-finish` to detect such navigation:

```
document.addEventListener('yt-navigate-finish', function(event) {
  var videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
  videoElement.addEventListener('ended', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
  });
});
```

Use devtools to see more events used by the page:

- [in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45365486): open Elements inspector and switch to the "Event listeners" subpanel
  or type `getEventListeners(document)` in the console (also works with `window` and any DOM element)
- [in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners): open Inspector and click the `ev` or `event` bubble to the right of `<html>` and other tags

Comment: thanks for additional tips as well. didn't know about them